# camel dynamic uri parameter

Tags: apache-camel, enterprise-integration

i want to implement the [content enricher pattern](http://camel.apache.org/content-enricher.html) with camel like this:

```
from("direct:x").enrich(dynamicUri,new MyAggregatorStrategy()).to("direct:y")
```

The dynamic uri is based on each message which comes from the `direct:x` channel.
So let's say there is an xml item coming in with the value `a` then the uri should be like http://someurl?q=a but the dynamicUri can only be a resource channel identifier.

I found some discussion on this [here](http://camel.465427.n5.nabble.com/How-to-get-a-dynamic-property-with-Camel-DSL-td475024.html) but i don't really understand it and the "HttpProducer.HTTP_URI" is not available in my workspace. Which camel package do I need for this and how do I do this? A processor maybe, but how?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What version of Camel are you using?

Many of those constant names for keys has been moved to to org.apache.camel.Exchange class in Camel 2.0 onwards. So take a look at this class for the HTTP_URI constant.
That's also what's listed on the wiki page
http://camel.apache.org/http

The Content Enricher doesn't support a dynamic URI, but some Camel components allow to set an uri as a header; such as the camel-http. Which mean in your case you can provide the uri as a header using the constant Exchange.HTTP_URI.

However that said, the Recipient List EIP pattern in Camel actually supports to evaluate the URI fully dynamic, and it also supports aggregation.
http://camel.apache.org/recipient-list.html

So you could implement the solution like this:

```
from("direct:x")
    .recipientList(header("dynamicUriHeader")).aggregationStrategy(new MyOwnAggregationStrategy())
    .to("direct:y");
```